# 複数サーバーでの運用に関して

Tags: dns

お世話になります。
現在私は独自ドメインをレンタルサーバーに設定して、一部のサブドメインをVPSに設定して利用しています。
今回レンタルサーバーの移行を行おうと思っているのですが、少し困っていることがあります。
VPSではcertbotでDNS認証を用いて、証明書の自動更新を行っていますが、APIで「_acme-challenge」というレコードを追加する必要があります。
現在利用しているレンタルサーバー付属のDNSはAPIで操作することができるのですが、移行先のレンタルサーバー付属のDNSはAPIでの操作はできないようです。
現在利用中のサーバーでAレコード等を移行先サーバーに向ければよいかと思っていたのですが、移行先サーバーのマニュアルを見ると、Let'sEncryptの無料証明書を設定する場合は、ネームサーバーを変更しないといけないようです。
ちなみに、Aレコードを移行先サーバーに向けた状態で、SSL設定をだめもとで試してみましたが、「ネームサーバーが当サービス指定のネームサーバーになっていません。」というエラーが出て、やはり設定できませんでした。
また、移行元のレンタルサーバーと移行先のレンタルサーバー両方のネームサーバーを指定するという方法も考え、利用していないドメインで試してみましたが、うまくいきませんでした。
それから、VPS上のcertbotでは、ワイルドカード証明書を発行しているため、httpでの認証は行えません。
また、「_acme.challenge」レコードを手動で追加するのは、証明書を自動更新させたいため、難しいです。
情報不足とは思いますが、ほかに方法はありますでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: > 移行先サーバーでLet'sEncryptの無料証明書を設定する場合は、ネームサーバーを変更しないといけないようです。 というのは具体的にどういった理由からそういった判断に至ったのでしょうか。

Comment: レンタルサーバーのマニュアルにそのように記載されています。また、ダメ元でSSL証明書の発行を試してみましたが、やはりエラーになってしまいました。

Comment: [XY問題に陥っているのでは？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2701/) ところでエラーの内容はどのようなものが出ているのでしょうか？

Comment: 「ネームサーバーが当サービス指定のネームサーバーになっていません。」というエラーが出ています。

Comment: 「Let'sEncryptの無料証明書を設定」をコマンドラインから「certbot」で行ってそのエラーが出るのでしょうか？そのエラーはもしかして、レンタルサーバのGUIやコンソールから出ていませんか？レンサバ由来のエラーならレンサバの環境や情報が無いと回答できないのでは？

Comment: 移行先のDNSに手動で _acme-challenge レコードを登録するわけにはいかないのでしょうか。

Comment: いえ、VPS上での証明書発行には成功しています。ご指摘の通り、エラー内容は、レンタルサーバー側で表示されたものです。質問文は修正しておきました。

Answer (score 1):

サーバのサービスとは関係ないサービスを使ってDNSを運用するのが結果的には早道だと思います。例えばCloudFlareのDNSサービスは無料でAPIも使えます。

今の環境のまま解決する方法もあるのかもしれませんが、質問の内容からは現在の環境も状況もよくわからないので、その方向で解決するのは難しいです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。結局別ドメインを取得して、そちらをVPS専用に割り当てることにしました。ありがとうございました。